# Doctrine 2.0 entitymanager->replace() equivalent

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

looking for a call that will ultimately result in a SQL of the form

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE....
```

In Doctrine 1.2, `$em->replace($obj_to_persist)` would achieve that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you asking for `Doctrine1.2` solution for that, or just plain SQL? Some code samples could help a lot.

Comment: the title of this question says 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 2 does not support `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE....`, `UPSERT`, `INSERT REPLACE`, etc.